# Divide time in the same time slot

Tags: php

I want to divide in the same time slot between the start time and end time.

Php Function :

```
public function time_slot_time() {
    $startTimeInterval = '15';
    $open = '2017-08-23T1:00:00-05:00';
    $close = '2017-08-23T5:00:00-05:00';
    // Logic
}
```

Output:

```
1:00PM - 1:15PM
1:15PM - 1:30PM
1:30PM - 1:45PM
1:45PM - 2:00PM
2:00PM - 2:15PM
...
3:15PM - 3:30PM
3:30PM - 4:45PM
4:45PM - 5:00PM
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PHP provides a very rich set of functions for working with Dates and Times, see http://php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php

In this case, the `DateTime`, `DateInterval` and `DatePeriod` classes are all very useful:

```
<?php
$interval = DateInterval::createFromDateString('15 minutes');

$begin = new DateTime('2017-08-23T1:00:00-05:00');
$end = new DateTime('2017-08-23T5:00:00-05:00');
// DatePeriod won't include the final period by default, so increment the end-time by our interval
$end->add($interval);

// Convert into array to make it easier to work with two elements at the same time
$periods = iterator_to_array(new DatePeriod($begin, $interval, $end));

$start = array_shift($periods);

foreach ($periods as $time) {
    echo $start->format('H:iA'), ' - ', $time->format('H:iA'), PHP_EOL;
    $start = $time;
}
```

`DatePeriod` implements PHP's [Traversable](http://php.net/manual/en/class.traversable.php) interface, which means you can loop over it like an array (or just convert it to one, in this case).

Comment: The first interval is repeated and the last interval is missing.
01:00AM - 01:00AM
01:00AM - 01:15AM
01:15AM - 01:30AM
01:30AM - 01:45AM
01:45AM - 02:00AM
02:00AM - 02:15AM
02:15AM - 02:30AM
02:30AM - 02:45AM
02:45AM - 03:00AM
03:00AM - 03:15AM
03:15AM - 03:30AM
03:30AM - 03:45AM
03:45AM - 04:00AM
04:00AM - 04:15AM
04:15AM - 04:30AM
04:30AM - 04:45AM

Comment: Also, we have given -05:00 time zone, so why it was not considered? Did you know?

Result will be : 08:00 - 08:15
08:15 - 08:30
08:30 - 08:45
08:45 - 09:00
09:00 - 09:15
09:15 - 09:30
09:30 - 09:45
09:45 - 10:00
10:00 - 10:15
10:15 - 10:30
10:30 - 10:45
10:45 - 11:00
11:00 - 11:15
11:15 - 11:30
11:30 - 11:45
11:45 - 12:00

Comment: @PratikKamani I've added fixes for your first comment. You didn't mention displaying the output in a different timezone, but if you want it in, say, **UTC** then you should be able to achieve this by calling `setTimeZone(new DateTimeZone('UTC'))` on the `DateTime` objects.

Comment: can you please let me know how can I get this result?
interval_time = 15 minute
duration = 20 min
The result will be
1:00  1:20
1:15 1:35
1:30 1:50
-----
End time will be add duration and start time will be add interval

Comment: Please help me to get this result.

public function time_slot_time() {
    $startTimeInterval = '15';
 $duration = '20';
    $open = '2017-08-23T1:00:00-05:00';
    $close = '2017-08-23T5:00:00-05:00';
    // Logic
}

open   - open+duration   
1:00PM - 1:20PM    
open+startTimeInterval    open+startTimeInterval+duration
1:15PM - 1:30PM
open+startTimeInterval    open+startTimeInterval+duration
1:30PM - 1:45PM
open+startTimeInterval    open+startTimeInterval+duration
1:45PM - 2:00PM
2:00PM - 2:15PM
...
3:15PM - 3:30PM
3:30PM - 4:45PM
4:45PM - 5:00PM

Answer (score 1):

```
public function time_slot_time() {
    $startTimeInterval = 15*60;
    $open = strtotime('2017-08-23T1:00:00-05:00');
    $close = strtotime('2017-08-23T5:00:00-05:00');
    do{
         echo date('H:i',$open).' - '.date('H:i',$open+$startTimeInterval). ' <br/>';
         $open = $open+$startTimeInterval;
    }while($open<$close);
}
```

My logic is to simply walk through the time slots and echo them... Nothing fancy. There are certainly better ways, but it should be simple enough for you to build around it.

Comment: Output is 
08:00 - 08:00
08:00 - 08:00
08:00 - 08:00
08:00 - 08:01
08:01 - 08:01
08:01 - 08:01
08:01 - 08:01
08:01 - 08:02
08:02 - 08:02
08:02 - 08:02

Comment: Did we need to convert $startTimeInterval on strtotime  ?

Comment: I am sorry, I corrected it... Needed to multiply by 60 for it to make 15 minutes as we are playing with seconds